# Find flutter sandwich menu button using flutter_driver

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, flutterdriver

Find flutter sandwich menu button using flutter_driver

```dart
    Scaffold(
        key: widget.scaffoldKey,
        drawer: Observer(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return DrawerMenu(
            user: controller.appStore.user,
            onTapLogout: controller.loginController.logout,
          );
        }),
        appBar: widget.appBar,
        body: widget.body);
```

[button to be identified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPMrT.png)

```dart
 test('test by inserting valid username and login', () async {
      await driver.tap(buttonFinder);

      expect(await driver.getText(loginName), "LoginName");
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sandwich menu you are referring to is called as `Drawer`, and you can tap on it using it's `toolTip` property.
If you long press on the drawer menu, it will show you a tooltip, as below:

[image]

Then, in your flutter driver test, you can identify this widget by declaring a finder using `byToolTip` method, as below:

`final drawerFinder = find.byTooltip('Open navigation menu');`

And then write your test as:

```
test('tap on drawer menu', () async {
        await driver.waitFor(drawerFinder);
        await driver.tap(drawerFinder);
        print('clicked on drawer');
      });
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution that is not 100% secure but permit you to not use tooltip is this:

```
test('OpenDrawer', () async {
      await driver.tap(find.descendant(
        of: find.byType('AppBar'),
        matching: find.byType('IconButton'),
        firstMatchOnly: true,
      ));
    });
```